# Laravel queue using redis is not stable?

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, redis

I am using redis-server ver 5.x on my vps ubuntu ver 20.x.Sometimes, few jobs do not execute and stop immediately.
My command to create worker:

```
php artisan queue:work --timeout=0 --tries=2
```

So maybe there is something wrong with redis-server? I tried to refresh the redis and even reinstall it. Nothing change.

P/s: No exception was threw in each job. Every jobs take only one second to execute. There is nothing unusual in logs of redis-server and Laravel app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I have an another app using the same redis server. And workers of the second app a executed jobs in the first app. Problem solved.